# How to make a specific object belong to a Player

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I want to make a type of a Spell that belongs to a Player, like a tool stay in Character Backpack but not literally. If a player press a button, the spell will be fired and how i can make this spell belongs to the player that pressed the button?

Comment: Could you clarify how exactly it will belong to a player? Do you want it to get added to the player's backpack when the spell is fired, or do you want a representation of the fact that the spell is owned by the Player?

Comment: The second option, the spell is owned by the player who fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're firing remotes from the client to the server, the first parameter of `OnServerEvent` identifies the player who fired the remote. If you wanted to make a spell "belong" to a player, you could pass the Instance when firing the remote and do the actions on the server event.

Local Script

```lua
local remote = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("FireSpell")
local spell = workspace.Spell

remote:FireServer(spell) -- fires the server with the instance passed
```

Server Script

```lua
local remote = game.ReplicatedStorage.FireSpell

remote.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr,partpassed) -- the first parameter will always be the player who fired the remote, so any parameters after define any parts passed from the client
    -- do things
    partpassed.Color = Color3.fromRGB(255,255,255)
end)
```

Comment: Yes, but i am creating the spell part in the Server Script after the RemoteEvent is fired

Comment: Create the spell part in the remote event and if you want, you can also give it a unique name, such as the username of the person who fired the remote.